# Android-Appropriate View For Horizontal & Vertical Scrolling Grid

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android and looking for advice on which particular view or views to use for an app. I am attempting to create an epg. I have done this on another platform and was wanting to migrate to android. After alot of reading and looking at examples I am little confused. To make a horizontal and vertical scrolling grid, would the gridview alone be enough to display the program titles. I say gridview alone, I mean the gridview in the main activity with a textview in resource xml. If not can somebody point me in the right direction, not asking for code just advice on the best way to go about the project. I am not worried about a channel list or time slot list only displaying the programming title in columns and rows that can scroll both directions. I anticipate the channel list being in a recyclerview separate form the grid. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to use cardview. Because gridview will give you 2 dimensional view which is not more customizable. Better you can go with cardview. 
For cardview, you need to add dependency. You can use cardview inside recycler view.

1. ***GridView*** - GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. The grid items are automatically inserted to the layout using a List Adapter. GridViews are particularly useful for displaying images in a structured fashion, for example if you’re designing a gallery app. To populate a GridView with data (whether that’s images, text, or a combination of the two) you’ll need to bind your data to the GridView using a ListAdapter
2. ***CardView*** - To create complex lists and cards with material design styles in your apps, you can use the RecyclerView and CardView widgets. CardView gives you an easy way of displaying data in Google Now-style cards. The Android SDK doesn’t include the CardView class, so you’ll need to add the CardView support library before you can use cards in your project.

To get bettter idea, you can visit [this](https://www.androidauthority.com/gridview-and-cardview-717319/) link.

Comment: I am using the Cardview along with Recyclerview for the channel list which works great. Just unsure of the programming info since I needed a scroll in both directions. I know there are apps like this already created just not sure what was used. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: It was my understanding that the GridView allowed for vertical and horizontal scrolling. I got my GridView populated and scrolls vertically but not horizontally.

Comment: Yes because GridView is 2 dimensional array. It won't scroll horizontally.. Also you won't customize it.